# logo at center and menu at right

Tags: css

I want to have a logo at the center of the page and then at right 3 menu items. Im trying to do this like below but its not working, the logo is not at the center of the page. Do you know how to do this?

html

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="content-full main_header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a>LOGO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="main_nav">
                <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a  href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

css

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.main_header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d6df;
  color:$color-white;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;

}

.logo{
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;

}

.menu{
  display: inline;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;

}

.main_nav li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-left: 1px solid #EFF2F5;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.main_nav a {
  color: gray;
}


.main_nav .create{
  color:green;
}

.main_nav .create:hover{
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: Position your `.menu` `absolute`, take it out the normal document flow. This will allow the `.logo` to occupy full available width, styled to `display: block; margin: auto;`. Then declare `position: relative` to the parent `header` element so that you can exercise some degree of control over the absolutely positioned `.menu` element.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

Add for menu:

```
.menu{
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;

}
```

And for DOM:

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="content-full main_header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a>LOGO</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
            <ul class="main_nav">
                <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a  href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Note that at smaller screens, the logo will overlap the menu.

Comment: Yes, but this normal habit, you must change it with media query, probably to put logo for one row and menu same. Like: @media screen and(max-width: 756px) { .menu, .logo-container {width: 100%;} }

Comment: Yes, the note was more for the OP and other readers. You can enhance your answer by adding your comment to your answer.

Comment: What ever, if the logo is on the same line, like it's on your example, the academic way is like you did first time...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with that the menu items dont appear.

Comment: If it's under logo container, add z-index for .menu {z-index: 9}